# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\DataPegawaiController::storeDetail(), 1 passed in

Tags: php, laravel, insert

i have problem like this. After insert new User to Pegawais table, i want to redirect to another view with user id parameter to define EducationHistory & WorkExperience data.
but when i

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\DataPegawaiController::storeDetail(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\data-pegawai\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

show method is where i fill my form to insert onto storeDetails method which is use user id parameter from show method route.

```
public function show($id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    
    return view('pegawai.create-details',['user'=>$user]);
}

public function storeDetail($id,Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->id_pegawai;
    
    dd($user);
    
    $pendidikanAttribute = [];
    $pendidikanAttribute['nama_sekolah'] = $request->nama_sekolah;
    $pendidikanAttribute['jurusan'] = $request->jurusan;
    $pendidikanAttribute['tahun_masuk'] = $request->tahun_masuk;
    $pendidikanAttribute['tahun_lulus'] = $request->tahun_lulus;
    $pendidikanAttribute['id_pegawai'] = $user->id_pegawai;;

    Pendidikan::create($pendidikanAttribute);

    $pengalamanAttribute = [];
    $pengalamanAttribute['perusahaan'] = $request->perusahaan;
    $pengalamanAttribute['jabatan'] = $request->jabatan;
    $pengalamanAttribute['tahun'] = $request->tahun;
    $pengalamanAttribute['keterangan'] = $request->keterangan;
    $pendidikanAttribute['id_pegawai'] = $user->id_pegawai;;

    PengalamanKerja::create($pengalamanAttribute);

    return redirect()->route('data-pegawai.index');
}
```

and this is my store detail view code :

```
<form method="POST" class="mt-4" action="{{route('data-pegawai.storeDetail',$user->id_pegawai)}}">
                        @csrf
```

this is my route :

```
Route::post('/data-pegawai/{id}/store-detail/', [DataPegawaiController::class,'storeDetail'])->name('data-pegawai.storeDetail');
```

Comment: can you also add your `route/web.php`  code for `storeDetail` method

Comment: please add your Routes also

Comment: i've added the route

Comment: Can you try change your parameter order in storeDetail method, Request as first and then the expected Id

Answer (score 2):

Remove `$id` from function `storedetials`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.